# Differences regarding \input@path between older version of LaTeX (e.g. 2019) and newer ones (e.g. 2021)

Tags: input

Suppose the directory `dir` contains a file `file.tex` with some part of the document. Then the document

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{./dir/}}% note the trailing slash
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\input{file}
\end{document}
```

typesets on TeXlive 2021 as well as on TeXlive 2019, while

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{./dir}}% no trailing slash
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\input{file}
\end{document}
```

works with TeXlive 2021, but fails with TeXlive 2019 (`file.tex` not found). Apparently newer versions of LaTeX add a slash per default, while older versions don't do it (such that they search for `./dirfile.tex` instead of `./dir/file.tex`).

So to be backwards compatible, one should add the trailing slash, even if this results in (harmless) double slashes in the paths used by LaTeX.

Is this the correct interpretation? Or is the observed behavior rather tied to the fact that one test was done on Linux (with TeXlive 2021, both documents typeset) and the other test on MacOS (TeXlive 2019, only the first document typesets)?

Comment: Your interpretation is likely correct.  Probably when I changed that part of the code I added the `/` for safety.  Or it's because `\l_file_search_path_seq` is documented to not need the trailing slash (so the code adds one), and `\input@path` is treated pretty much in the same way, so it ends up with two slashes now.  I can check more carefully later

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik the original design definitely was documented as requiring a trailing /  allowing an optional trailing one (but not making a doubled //) would be fine I think, I didn't do that in 1993 as was needing to cope with other syntax VMS, atari etc so you couldn't assume the path syntax was `/` separated paths..

Comment: It seems that the difference is was indeed caused by preemptively adding the `/` in the code (the difference of `\l_file_search_path_seq` and `\input@path` seems to be of little importance here).  @gernot do you know of a practical effect of this change that may cause problems?  I'm not sure if compatibility with Atari machines is a good enough reason to change the behaviour back ;-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik No, no practical effect, except that omitting the slash breaks backwards-compatibility, which happened in my case: an application run on several different TeX installations mysteriously didn't find files on one, while it worked fine on the other. And I didn't find any postings about this behavior. At least under Unix/Linux, double slashes are treated as one. It may just happen, like with me, that when seeing double slashes people try to avoid them and remove the trailing slash.